# Fetching data in LWC via getRecord vs. Apex

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I don't know how to ask this question properly - so please bear with me.

Let's say I query an account via `getRecord`:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Id', 'Account.Name'] })
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
}
```

And one (or more) via a custom Apex method `getAccounts`:

```
@wire(getAccounts, { accountId: '$recordId' })
wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
}
```

With `getRecord` I access the `Name` of the account like this:

```
data.fields.Name.value
```

Via the Apex query, I access the `Name` of the first account like this:

```
data.[0].Name
```

Two major differences here - first of all, I don't have to access the fields of an object via `.fields`, and second of all - I don't have to use `.value` to get the field's value. Why is that? Why will `getRecord` return an object in this special wrapper? And why doesn't my Apex query?

The follow-up code doesn't care where the account is coming from but I have to handle it differently because it's returned differently. Surely there's a reason for that and an explanation in the docs somewhere? Can anybody shed some light on this? If so, and you have this "issue" as well - what's your solution?

If this question is not well-written - please help me to improve it and not just downvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference in structure is simply that the data is returned differently by these two services (one standard and one custom).

Your custom service is probably returning simple SObject data, which is essentially a [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_json_overview.htm) representation of records, related record lists and fields with values.

On the other hand, the Get Record wire returns a whole bunch of additional information. You can read about the structure in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-record.html).

For `field.value` have a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_field_value.htm#ui_api_responses_field_value) where you'll see that a field provides both the "raw" value and the display value:

| Property | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| displayValue | String | The displayable value for a field. |
| value | Object | The value of a field in its raw data form. |

The returned data from both is accessed as JavaScript objects. You could write some JS code to traverse the Get Record response and turn it into the same structure as a simple `SObject`. Just make sure to create a new JavaScript object from it - both return "immutable" (Read only) values.

Comment: Is it possible to convert a User Interface API Response Body into a simple object? Does such a feature exist? Or can I annotate my query so that it returns such an object?

Comment: @Semmel you would need to build a custom wrapper in your apex class that mirrors (some or all) of what GetRecord does, and then return that to the LWC instead of just returning the List<SObject>. Or if you are building a reusable component and you can't anticipate if the data will come from GetRecords or Apex, you can build a JS function to convert the generic Apex return into a GetRecords style wrapper.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm doing at the moment - I just wondered if this is a problem that also has a "standard" solution. But a custom wrapper or conversion is good enough. :)